# Set day to "first day of month", if it's set, set to previous month

Tags: php, date, time, strtotime

I want to set the first day of this month (Y-M-01) if day > 1. 
But if the day already is the first day of this month, it should give me "-1 month" instead.
The same should be able to happen when going forward. (+1 month)

How do I manage this in php?

(Update)
Got this code working for going backwards but I can't use the same method for going forward as the last day of the month could be 28, 29, 30 or 31.
Should be using last day of month instead but I don't know how to..

```
if (date("j", strtotime('today', $time)) == 1) {
    $beginmon = strtotime('first day of last month', $time);
} else {
    $beginmon = strtotime('first day of this month', $time);
}
```

Comment: Maybe show us what you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds simple

```
<?php

if(date("j")>1)
{
echo date("Y-m-01");
}
else
{
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-1 month"));
}

?>
```

**Edit**

Can be modified for your environment as

```
<?php
if(date("j")==1)
{
$beginmon = strtotime(date("Y-m-01"));
}
else
{
$beginmon=strtotime("-1 month");
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks! Have done something like your code although it won't work for going forward.. updated my description of the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = strtotime('first day of this month', time());
if (date("Y M dd", $date) == date("Y M dd", time())){
     $date = strtotime('first day of last month', time());
}
```